# Random number in C

Tags: c, intel-fpga

I'm writing my own method to generate a random number with C as follows:

```
int randomNumber(){  
    int catch = *pCOUNTER;  
    int temp = catch;  
    temp /= 10;  
    temp *= 10;  
    return (catch - temp);  
}
```

`pCounter` is basically a pointer to a register in the device I'm using. The number in that register is always increasing so my idea is to take the first digit only.

At some point, the number returned becomes larger than 9 and I'm not sure if the problem is in my code or the device itself. The device is an Altera DE1 board.

Can anyone please help with that?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope this is a homework assignment.

Comment: You need to be careful of the signs of your integers.  If `*pCOUNTER` is negative, then your method and all the other suggestions so far produce the wrong answer.  If you cast a negative integer to an unsigned type, it will appear to be large.

Comment: Note that if `*pCOUNTER` is unsigned, this can return negative values when `*pCOUNTER >= 2^32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you're trying to do in your code:

```
int catch = *pCOUNTER;
return (catch % 10); // Returns only the ones digit
```

However, I question if this approach is anywhere close to being reasonably random...

Comment: Chosen by fair dice roll. Guaranteed to be random.

Answer (score 4):

Did you declare `pCounter` as volatile?

```
volatile unsigned *pCounter = (unsigned *)0xBADDECAF;

int randomNumber(){
    return *pCounter % 10;
}
```

Comment: Note that even if it _is_ marked volatile, many compilers are notorious for not always handling volatile variables properly: see http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/emsoft08-preprint.pdf for an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not looking to use %= instead of /= & *=?

Comment: My logic is: if the catch is 1234 then temp /= 10 is 123 and temp *= 10 is 1230 so (catch - temp) = 1234 - 1230 = 4.

Comment: @Tomalak: `2 - 0` is still `2`.

Comment: @Uqi %= makes it less ambiguous. Other issues arise if *pCounter points to an unsigned. Have you tested what happens to this function when things start overflowing?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem might be an 'optimization' introduced by the compiler - if you don't have `pCOUNTER` declared with the correct volatility, the compiler could be reading through the pointer more than once. I have no idea how many registers your processor might have - if there's not enough to hold `catch` in a register, it might read it multiple times (once to get something to do the `temp` calculations on, and again for the final return value).

Try the following, which should ensure that the `pCOUNTER` device/register is read exactly once:

```
int randomNumber(){  
    int catch = *(int volatile*)pCOUNTER;  
    int temp = catch;  
    temp /= 10;  
    temp *= 10;  
    return (catch - temp);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a random digit (0-9 only), try this modification of your method.

```
int randomNumber(){  
    return ((*pCOUNTER) % 10);  
}
```

This isn't very random, though. If it's always increasing, presumably at a known rate then it's 100% predictable, not random at all.

Is the `rand()` function not allowed on that Altera board?

**Edit:**

You could always write your own PRNG. I did a Google search for "simple random number generator code", and found several simple examples. The simplest ones are along these lines:

```
int randomNumber()
{
    static long a = SomeSeedValue;

    a = (a * SomeNumber + AnotherNumber) % SomeLargePrimeNumber;
    return a % 65536;
}
```

Comment: Yea, I guess it's more "arbitrary" than "random".

Answer (score -1):

If you want to arbitrarily limit the result to 9:

```
return (catch - temp)%10;
```

I recommend using a macro constant to abstract the '10' though, otherwise it's a magic number.